# popToViewController throws NSRangeException

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a navigation controller stack, let's say A(root)->B->C->C->C->C->D. Now I want to click a button in D to pop me directly to B. Referring to some solutions at Stackoverflow, I used:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

But it throws NSRangeException:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]
```

I don't understand the reason since there is nothing to do with number "3" and "2" in the error message.

Extra information in case you need them:

1. I used segue between A and B, and "pushViewController" afterwards.
2. I hid the navigation bar of each controller.(which is very important for the design)

Hope you can help me! Thanks!

Comment: how can u place a same VC say C that many times, have u presented it or pushed the same C vc

Comment: They are of the same class but have different content such as tag and image.

Comment: Can you show the result of this line NSLog(@"%@",[self.navigationController viewControllers]); where thecrash done

Comment: `"<KCCategoryViewController: 0x8d1e720>",
    "<KCQuoteListViewController: 0x8f7fef0>",
    "<KCQuestionaireViewController: 0x8d6bcc0>",
    "<KCQuestionaireViewController: 0x8f78f10>",
    "<KCQuestionaireViewController: 0x8d9f5e0>",
    "<KCQuestionaireViewController: 0x8f845c0>"`

Comment: Haha problem solved. Guys I was so silly! The problem actually occurs when try to push a entry into core data inside D. Nothing to do with the popToViewController function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (UIViewController *controllers in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

    if ([controllers isKindOfClass:[DesiredViewController class]]) { 

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controllers
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Still throws the same exception.

Comment: debug the code, and make sure if B is in your navigation hierarchy.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I printed the stack before every push using `NSLog(@"%@", [self.navigationController viewControllers]);`, and the result is `"A","B","C","C","C","C"`at the last push before D.

Comment: Haha problem solved. Guys I was so silly! The problem actually occurs when try to push a entry into core data inside D. Nothing to do with the popToViewController function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
Let view controllers in stack are A->B->C->D->E
```

if you want to pop to C then

```
for(UIViewController *vc in [self.navigationController.viewControllers])
{
     if(vc isKindOfClass [C class])
     {
          [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *existingControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
 B *theB;
 for(UIViewController *eachCtrl in existingControllers)
 {

     if([eachCtrl isKindOfClass:[B class]])
     {
        int Bx = [existingControllers indexOfObject:eachCtrl]
        theB = [existingControllers objectAtIndex:Bx];
     }

 }

 //Now do your popping of B controller
 if(nil != theB)
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:theB animated:YES];
```

and I think you are making a mistake of creating lot of 'C' instances.
and also verify existingControllers have your B instance in it while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if ([[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]>1) {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing wrong with using:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers]    objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

If the navigation stack is  A(root)->B->C->C->C->C->D. I have tested and attached a sample project for this.

[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxzxjbb6meoyaho/TestManyPush.zip?dl=0)